# Vue v-for works if there are only 7 elements in the array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I can't understand why vuejs works only if the result I have from an axios GET request has a maximum of 7 elements.

This is the code:

```
<template>
    <div class="chat-messages">
        <div v-for="message in messages" :key="message.id" class="message">
            <div class="avatar">
                <img :src="message.user.profile_image">
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <p class="user">{{ message.user.name }}</p>
                <p>
                    {{ message.text }}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            messages: [],
        }
    },
    created() {
        axios.get('/messages')
            .then((res) => {
                this.messages = res.data;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.response);
            })
    }
}
</script>
```

And this is how my JSON looks like ( just an example ):

```
[
{
"id": 142,
"user_id": 2,
"text": "Minima delectus saepe eos aliquam.",
"created_at": "2019-05-09 16:28:56",
"updated_at": "2019-05-09 16:28:56",
"user": {
"id": 2,
"name": "Libbie Tremblay Sr.",
"email": "hilda.koss@example.org",
"profile_image": "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
"email_verified_at": "2019-05-09 16:28:44",
"created_at": "2019-05-09 16:28:44",
"updated_at": "2019-05-09 16:28:44"
}
},
{
"id": 143,
"user_id": 15,
"text": "Officia fugit minus doloremque dolorem.",
"created_at": "2019-05-09 16:28:56",
"updated_at": "2019-05-09 16:28:56",
"user": {
"id": 15,
"name": "Estevan Krajcik",
"email": "ryan.rashad@example.org",
"profile_image": "https://via.placeholder.com/150",
"email_verified_at": "2019-05-09 16:28:44",
"created_at": "2019-05-09 16:28:44",
"updated_at": "2019-05-09 16:28:44"
}
}
]
```

If I send more than 7 elements, then it tells me:

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile_image' of null"

found in
```

If I remove that part of code then it says that it cannot read the 'name'..

This is so strange...

Comment: Could you show the actual data? This looks like a data issue, not a code issue. It's acting like  the eighth element in your array is missing the `user` object.

Comment: It's not missing, everything is there, the example above shows you the format used by me to send this data.

Comment: You were right, now I see that there are elements who have user: null, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are trying to get a profile image off an object that does not exist.

You should always check data before referencing an object e.g.

```
<div class="avatar" v-if="message.user && message.user.profile_image">
    <img :src="message.user.profile_image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<label for="designimage">Design Image </label><br>
@if ($designs->design_image == NULL)
    <img src="{{    asset('images/design_image/defult.jfif') }}"  height="300"       width="300">//set defult image path
@else
    <img src="{{ asset('images/design_image/'.$designs->design_image) }}"           height="300" width="300">//orignal image path
@endif
```

Comment: Hello. Please avoid code only answer. Explain what you did and why.